# double casting, to get from uint16 to int32 while keeping the sign

Tags: c++

I have an uint16_t Variable, BUT the data stored in it is an int16_t value.

I now want to cast the uint16_t Variable to int32_t while keeping the sign.

(I know it's tagged with c but the code is c++ but that doesn't matter here, because I am using the c-typecasts)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdint.h>

using namespace std;


int main() {    
    uint16_t source = 32769; // is actually -32767

    cout << source                      << endl
         << (int16_t) source            << endl
         << (int32_t) source            << endl
         << (int32_t)(int16_t) source   << endl;
}
```

> Output:
>
> 32769
>
> -32767
>
> 32769
>
> -32767

The double cast is giving me the correct result.

I only want to know if a double cast is valid standard c code, where every compiler will behave the same way. Or could some compiler just skip the first cast or whatever?

Comment: You could at least use `cstdio` and so on, but you probably know better.

Comment: If you want c then just use `printf` instead of `cout`. If you want c++ then change the tag. The answer may be different depending on the language.

Comment: There is no short-circuiting in casting. So just use proper brackets to be sure about the order, and you should be good to go: `(int32_t)((int16_t) source)`

Comment: The casting behavior does matter as C++ has very specific types of casts and even C-style casting follows procedures defined in the standard

Comment: `(int32_t)(int16_t) source` the information is "destroyed" as soon as you cast to 16 bits. There's no way back.

Comment: It is valid but implementation-defined behaviour. Why don't you just write `int i; if(source > 36767) i = source - 65536;`?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre He is not casting from `int32_t` to `int16_t` but the other way round.

Comment: anyway I stumbled here a bit by accident, question was tagged C and has C-style casts... forget it

Answer (score 3):

> I only want to know if a double cast is valid standard c code

It is valid C and C++ code insofar as the value being converted from an unsigned to a signed integer can be represented in the target type. In this case it cannot be as it exceeds the documented value range of an `int16_t`.

> where every compiler will behave the same way. Or could some compiler just skip the first cast or whatever?

This is complicated because you're in C++ but asking about C. So I'll answer for both. In C++ up until C++20 and C this is *implementation defined*. What that means is that a compiler must have a documented behavior, however that behavior is not guaranteed to be the same.

As aforementioned this is changing in c++20 to acknowledge that almost no modern implementation supports anything but Two's complement integers at which point the result is defined as "the unique value of the destination type equal to the source value modulo 2<sup>n</sup> where n is the number of bits used to represent the destination type" [Source](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Integral_promotion)

Comment: Glad you've been slightly faster than me - was about to write something similar (not covering the C++20 issue, though), but my text couldn't compete with yours...

Comment: @Aconcagua I actually need to look into if C20 is changing too, I wouldn't be surprised if they are harmonizing with C++ on it as the behavior is de-facto defined AFAIK

Comment: I'm not sure that your interpretation of *implementation defined* is right in this particular case. The fixed width integer (signed) types, from [<cstdint>](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cstdint) are *"signed integer type with width of exactly 8, 16, 32 and 64 bits respectively
with no padding bits **and using 2's complement for negative values
(provided only if the implementation directly supports the type)** "*. To my understanding, *if* they are supported, the cast is well defined.

Comment: @Bob__ the cast is "defined" either way, the result is not (yet). It's worth noting if you're working from the latest draft that this IS fully defined in C++20. I understand your point however because it requires the implementation to specify if it is two's complement (AFAIK all current ones are, hence "de-facto defined") that means that anything that relies on that is (until c++20) implementation defined _technically_.

Comment: C++20 requireing 2's complement: Then they should have made signed integer overflow well defined as well. Is that so?